# Google play resource override string value

Tags: android, resources

I have app that supports few languages. When I use one of supported languages everything works pretty well, but when I use default language (phone on unsupported language(hebrew)) one of my strings overrides by string from play services package. As the result this specific string translates to unsupported language.(Hebrew) Resource path looks usual.

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iconFeedback"
                android:elevation="3dp"
                android:text="@string/accept"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

[image]

Why it can happens?
Thanks in advice